# Not able to read excel file which I created through open function?

Tags: python

I created one excel file and wrote something in it. I am trying to read that file through pandas - dataframe, but I am getting error

```
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record
```

Code -

```
import pandas as pd
a = open("D:\\Joseph\\abcsaa.xlsx","a")
a.write("Hello all")
p = pd.read_excel("D:\\Joseph\\abcsaa.xlsx")
p
```

Thanks for the answers. I need to store tick data in a excel and then read it through dataframe.

What is the use of open function in python for excel file if I have to use other modules for this ?

Comment: You created a file, but just because its name has the extension `xlsx` doesn't make it an Excel file, and cannot be read as such.

Answer (score 1):

Excel file cannot be created with inbuilt python open function. You have to use openpyxl package to read and write excel files.
Some besic operations using openpyxl

```
import openpyxl

# Open Workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='example.xlsx', data_only=True)

# Get All Sheets
a_sheet_names = wb.get_sheet_names()
print(a_sheet_names)

# Get Sheet Object by names
o_sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
print(o_sheet)

# Get Cell Values
o_cell = o_sheet['A1']
print(o_cell.value)

o_cell = o_sheet.cell(row=2, column=1)
print(o_cell.value)

o_cell = o_sheet['H1']
print(o_cell.value)

# Sheet Maximum filled Rows and columns
print(o_sheet.max_row)
print(o_sheet.max_column)
```

Answer (score 1):

Install this if you don't already have it.

```
pip install XlsxWriter
```

Code:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("D:\\Joseph\\abcsaa.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello world')

workbook.close()
```

XLsxWriter can do a lot and has great documentation [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/contents.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the file already exists, open it the first time with

```
a = pd.read_excel('path/aabcsaa.xlsx')
```

Else, create a pandas dataframe with

```
a = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and then save it using

```
pd.to_excel('path/aabcsaa.xlsx')
```

Answer (score -2):

You opened your file in append mode (`"a"`). If you want to read it with read_excel by passing the filename, you need to close the file before:

```
a.close()
```

And the content of the file needs to be in valid excel format.